# REASSIGN/DROP OWNED BY for all databases on postgres server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a situation where I am trying to remove a list of roles from a particular database, but that role is in use on multiple databases on the server.

As per [the documentation for Dropping Roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/role-removal.html), I have followed the instructions:

```sql
REASSIGN OWNED BY doomed_role TO successor_role;
DROP OWNED BY doomed_role;
-- repeat the above commands in each database of the cluster
DROP ROLE doomed_role;
```

The documentation also states:

> Because REASSIGN OWNED [and DROP OWNED] cannot access objects in other databases, it is necessary to run it in each database that contains objects owned by the role.

As expected, when I run the above commands:

```ruby
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
conn.execute("REASSIGN OWNED BY viewer_role TO postgres")
conn.execute("DROP OWNED BY viewer_role")
conn.execute("DROP ROLE IF EXISTS viewer_role")
```

I am getting the error message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DependentObjectsStillExist:
ERROR: role "viewer_role" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:
35 objects in database inst2
35 objects in database inst3
35 objects in database inst4
```

Within the context of a rails app, how do call `REASSIGN OWNED` and `DROP OWNED` for all databases?

My guess is that I'm going to have to connect to each database.  I've found a solution that works:

```ruby
module DBS
  @@connections = {}

  # get all databases
  conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection;
  dbs = conn.select_values('SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false')

  # create a connection to each database - this will raise lots and lots of warnings
  dbs.each do |db_name|
    @@connections[db_name] ||=
      begin
        config = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
        config = config.merge({database: db_name})

        model = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base)
        self.const_set("#{db_name.classify}", model) # This is needed as rails raises an error if the class does not have a name :@
        model.establish_connection(config)

        model.connection
      end
  end

  def self.connections
    @@connections
  end
end

roles.each do |role_name|
  DBS.connections.values.each do |conn|
    conn.execute("REASSIGN OWNED BY #{role_name} TO postgres")
    conn.execute("DROP OWNED BY #{role_name}")
  end

  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DROP ROLE IF EXISTS #{role_name}")
end
```

However, is it possible to to do the same thing just using the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` already established?

Comment: Correct, you need to reassign/drop for each database. It's an architectural limitation in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Okay, thanks!  That just leaves me finding a nicer way, if any, to issue the commands to all databases from rails.